# Error when selecting rows with checkbox in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I have the following problem: I am following these tutorials to be able to save the data in array through each row selected by a checkbox.

- https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/
- https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/abhbs4x8/

As in the provided link, I receive data in JSON to load my dataTable, now I am seen in need of, by a button to bring new data to my dataTable for it and added some more functions to the code that is in the link that Provide, and are as follows:

**To delete the datatable:**

```js
function destroy_data_table(){
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  if (table != undefined){
  table .fnDestroy();
  }
}
```

**In the click of the button I destroy my datatable and call the function that loads a new one:**

```js
$("#btnNewDatatable").click(function (){
  destroy_data_table();
  new_data();
});
```

**And this is the function that reloads the datatable:**

```js
function new_data(){
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  "sAjaxSource": //Here I return in json what my server      sends,
  "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ){
    oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax({
    "dataType": 'json',
    "type": "POST",
    "url": sSource,
    "data": aoData,
    "success": function(result){
      fnCallback(result);
    }
   });
  },
  responsive: true,
  'columnDefs': [{
    'targets': 0,
    'searchable':false,
    'orderable':false,
    'width':'1%',
    'className': 'dt-body-center',
    'render': function (data, type, full, meta){
      return '<input type="checkbox">';
    }
   }]
  });
 }
```

My problem is that when loading the new databale, and when selecting a row, this continues to show me the data from the previous datatable, I made a console.log a var rows_selected = []; Which is in charge of storing the data of each selected row, I am badly destroying the table or what could be my mistake?

Comment: Delete datatable does not look right, you should be getting errors.

Comment: In fact it was the first thing I thought, I checked it and if it destroys the table, because it loads the new data correctly, but when I select rows the array, I load the data of the previous datatable

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

keep this table variable as global for ease.

```
    //Initialize First time

    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
          ......
          }

    function destroy_data_table(){
    table.clear().draw();
    }
```

instead of destroy.